# Powershell: Get specific domain email address from their proxy addresses

Tags: powershell

Using Powershell I want to parse through all users in the domain and pull out just a specific email address from their proxy addresses. My users have multiple email addresses in their proxy addresses. I want to get just the email address from each user that ends in a specific domain. Example if each user had @test.com,@franklin.com, and @thisone.com. I want to pull just the @thisone.com only. I am starting with this but want to pull only the one that ends with @thisone.com

Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties proxyaddresses | Select-Object Name, @{L = "ProxyAddresses"; E = { ($_.ProxyAddresses -like 'smtp:*') -join ";"}} | Export-Csv -Path C:\PowerShell\AdUsersProxyAddresses.csv -NoTypeInformation

Comment: you're almost there, it's just `$_.ProxyAddresses -like 'smtp:*@thisone.com'`

Answer (score 0):

```
(Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties proxyaddresses).proxyaddresses | ?{$_ -match '@thisone.com'}
```

This gives you only the proxyaddress back which matches '@thisone.com'

Comment: Worked like a champ. Thank you Santiago!

Comment: The script is doing exactly as I need. My question is how would I separate the email addresses in to separate columns in the export? Right now the output has the email addresses separated by “;” into one column. Can I make it so the export right away puts them in separate columns?

Comment: I figured it out. Thank you.

Comment: Using the below format:  

Import-Csv "\\server\input.csv" | Foreach {Get-ADUser -Filter "EmployeeID -eq '$($_.EID)'" -Properties EmployeeID, SamAccountName, Enabled, proxyAddresses } | Select-Object EmployeeID, SamAccountName, Enabled, @{L = "ProxyAddresses"; E = { ($_.ProxyAddresses -like '*@mycompany.org' ) -join ";"}}

I would also like to find any other proxy addresses a user has that are not from in '*@mydomain.org' but are primary  that start with 'SMTP:*

Example @{L = "ProxyAddresses"; E = { ($_.ProxyAddresses -like '*@mycompany.org' ) AND LIKE THIS -join ";"}}

Comment: Example @{L = "ProxyAddresses"; E = { ($_.ProxyAddresses -like '*@mycompany.org' ) AND LIKE THIS -join ";"}}  Apologizes I haven't figured out formatting yet.